# Prettier форматирует код при авто сохранении

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Раньше: стоит авто сохранение, код просто сохраняется. При `ctrl+s` код форматируется.
После обновления VSCode началась проблема, теперь при автосохранении происходит форматирование кода, что не нужно.
Если в "Format On Save" убрать галочку, то код вообще не форматируется, в том числе и по `ctrl+s`.
Какие настройки установить, что бы было авто сохранение, но без произвольного форматирования?

Answer (score 0):

Нашла!!! Теперь это так: параметр `Format On Save` - галочку убрать, и автоматического форматирования не будет.

Команды:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> - форматирование документа,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - форматирование выделенной части кода.